# Java Map<String,String[]> how to sum values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have such a map `Map<String,String[]>` I want to sum up its values, values ​​are String tables I know that they are numbers. Please show me how to do it with streams. I've tried :

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
int sum = map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Comment: can you post an example, what do you want to sum `keys` or all `values`?

Comment: I tried so int sum =mapa.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum(); this map is Map<String,String[]> map

Comment: map.values().stream().flatMapToInt(num -> Arrays.stream(num).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)).sum()

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having with it?

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I meant it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the question`map.values()` returns the `Set` of `String[]`, you should

> 1) First stream the `Set<String[]>`
>
> 2) Then convert `String[]` to array stream, and string to int

```
int sum = map.values()
             .stream()
             .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
             .sum();
```